# Redefine Attribute of Metaclass when extending Stereotypes

Tags: inheritance, attributes, enterprise-architect, stereotype

I have an issue, open question regarding extending stereotypes in Enterprise Architect.

Each attribute in my custom `stereotype Z`, which extends `Metaclass A`, has the property field `Redefined Property`. They way I understand it, I can choose to redefine an attribute of the extended Metaclass. Is this understanding correct?

What I tried:

- Add attribute `really_weird_attr_name` in my `metaclass A`, as the attributes do not show up...
- Add attribute 'much_better_attr_name' in my `stereotype Z`
- Select `A.really_weird_attr_name` from the `Redefined Property`

When I export the profile with Spezialise-> Publish Tech -> Publish Diagram as UML Profile, there is no hint or whatsoever, that the property has been redefined:

```
[...]
                <TaggedValues>
                    <Tag name="much_better_attr_name" type="char" description="" unit="" values="" default=""/>
                </TaggedValues>
[...]
```

[image: the above example, where Schema redefines Tablespace]

Comment: Can you add an image of your UML profile diagram?

Comment: Diving deep here. You could ask that on Sparx' forum (with a link to here). Maybe Paolo has used this (or another geek). I haven't so far.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I added an image

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not correct.

Redefining properties is only possible if your stereotype redefines another stereotype, and you keep the exact same property name.

For more details see the EA manual on [Redefine Stereotypes in another Profile](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/modeling_frameworks/redefine_ster_other_prof.html)

Also «table» is a special stereotype in EA that allows for some special behavior in the tool like being able to set things like **not null**, and **PK**. This behavior will not be triggered by the stereotype «snowflaketable».

Comment: So it's maybe worth a shot, to redefine table with my «snowflaketable»-stereotype?

Comment: @dmeu, no I don't think you should try to redefine the table stereotype, unless maybe if you keep the same stereotype name (so myProfile::table). In that case EA will hopefully trigger the special table behavior like it does with the standard EAUML::table.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to make the linked example. It is not clear to me how to 'Draw a Redefines relationship', the option is not displayed amongst the other options, such as "Substitution,Generalization, etc"

Comment: the 15.2-documentation has a slightly different wording: "Draw a Generalization from the redefining stereotype to the redefined stereotype, and give the Generalization the <<redefines>> stereotype.". Anyhow, when I enter the stereotype dialog of the Generalization, there is no Redefines-Stereotype to be found...

Comment: @dmeu indeed, you need to create the «redefines» stereotype one yourself.